# Python Couldn't parse HTML from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have tried this below code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = 'https://myip.ms/'

page = 1
req = requests.get(URL + str(page))
soup = bs (req.text, 'html.parser')
print (soup)
```

this code working for some websites but not working for most of websites like myip.ms

Comment: Most websites use JavaScript to fill in details in the page. JavaScript does not run when using `requests.get()` - for that you need a webbrowser.

Comment: I just went to said website and it prompted me to verify that I am not a robot. myip.ms - like many other websites - seems to not want automated tools accessing their website.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me. But what essentially are you trying to achieve here? Your code appends "1" to the end of the URL and then visits it. If the page with those URL parameters doesn't exist on the server - it will give you errors. For this case: https://myip.ms/1 exists, but no surprise that any other page could give you errors